# How do I dynamically create equally sized divs to fill the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made an interactive 16x16 grid, who's `div`s grown and shrink based on screen size.

```js
let x = 0;
let container = document.getElementById("container");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  createLongContainers();
  let longContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".longContainer");
  createBoxes(longContainers);
});

function createLongContainers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "longContainer";
    div.style.display = "flex";
    div.style.flexDirection = "row"
    var lcHeight = ((100 / 16) + "%");
    div.style.height = lcHeight;
    div.style.width = "100vh";
    container.appendChild(div);

  }
}

function createBoxes(longContainers) {
  longContainers.forEach((div) => {


    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      let box = document.createElement('div');
      box.className = "gridSquare";
      let boxWidth = ((100 / 16) + "%");
      box.style.height = "100%";
      box.style.width = boxWidth;
      box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      box.onmouseover = function() {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        box.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
      };

      box.onmouseout = function() {
        box.style.transitionDuration = "3s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      div.appendChild(box);

    }

  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Colorful Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <!-- Removes white border around page-->
</body>

</html>
```

I can't figure out how to fill the screen with this grid, while maintaining their square shape and ability to shrink in relation to the screen size.

For example, when I change
`div.style.width = "100vh";`
to
`div.style.width = "100vw";`
and add more boxes so they aren't stretched, they lose their ratio when the screen size is changed.

I know I need to dynamically create fixed size `div`s based on the current screen size, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: do you mean you want to put boxes on top of your animated container?? or just stretch it and make it equal??

Comment: Firstly, Do you think it's possible to force a square into a rectangle? Or simply put, would a square fit into the entire area of a rectangle? No, it's not possible. a 16x16 Grid with square blocks will not fit a rectangular screen and not lose its WxH ratio.

Comment: Or maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly. I've put your code into a snipped and tried to first use css to achieve your goal. In order to keep the blocks as square you gonna have to let the grid grow based on the screen with and height... so the number of animated blocks must be created based on the view port width and height sizes.

Comment: @MosiaThabo I see what you're saying, I can't have the ability to resize based on current window size and always have squares.

Comment: @JaydenDafoe-Dunn Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chanegd your script a little and sued CSS-Grid over Flexbox which will make everythign easier IMHO. Also you onyl need to run 1 script as it includes 256 boxes (16x16) instead of 16 rows that then again include 16 child boxes.

I also removed the `style`-statements from JS completely. I add the styles through CSS to shorten the JS code.

Then I used `aspect-ratio` to maintain a square-size. Alternativly you can hardcode it.

Then I used `media queries` within CSS to check if the screen size is in `landscape` or in `portrait`-mode and set the width of the squares to either `to` 1fr`or`calc(100vh / 16)`.

Last but not least I use `overflow: hidden` on the container to hide the elements that would not fit the viewport anymore. That is the onyl way to fill the entire screen without breaking the aspect-ration of the boxes.

```js
let x = 0;
let container = document.getElementById("container");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  createBoxes();
});

function createBoxes() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#container').forEach((div) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      let box = document.createElement('div');
      box.className = "gridSquare";
      box.onmouseover = function() {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        box.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
      };

      box.onmouseout = function() {
        box.style.transitionDuration = "3s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      div.appendChild(box);

    }

  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, calc(100vh / 16));
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  }
}

.gridSquare {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Colorful Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <!-- Removes white border around page-->
</body>

</html>
```

I saw your comment that you wanted to use 20px squares. I changd the script and CSS to adjust for that. I got rid of the media queries and changed the number of columns to `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20px, 1fr));` That will include as many columns of at least 20px and fill them with as many as possible. Then it upsize the columns to leave no white-space.

To create as many boxes as needed you can create a ridicolous number of boxes. However this will cause serious performance issues.

Therefore, I wrote this little script:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var containerWidth = Math.floor(container.offsetWidth / 20),
    containerHeight = Math.ceil(container.offsetHeight / 20);
var squareAmount = containerWidth * containerHeight;
```

This script get the width and height of the viewport. It divides both by 20. The width can be rounded down but the height must be rounded up to allow the overflow. Then I multiply both values and get the sum of them. That sum is used in the loop as target so it will only create as many boxes as actually needed:

```js
let x = 0;
let container = document.getElementById("container");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  createBoxes();
});

function createBoxes() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#container').forEach((div) => {
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var containerWidth = Math.floor(container.offsetWidth / 20),
        containerHeight = Math.ceil(container.offsetHeight / 20);
    var squareAmount = containerWidth * containerHeight;
    for (var i = 0; i < squareAmount; i++) {
      let box = document.createElement('div');
      box.className = "gridSquare";
      box.onmouseover = function() {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        box.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
      };

      box.onmouseout = function() {
        box.style.transitionDuration = "3s";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      div.appendChild(box);

    }

  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20px, 1fr));
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gridSquare {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Colorful Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <!-- Removes white border around page-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, awesome! Yeah CSS-grid seems like a better way to do this.

Comment: @JaydenDafoe-Dunn I just saw your comment `These divs would have a fixed size, lets say 20px x 20px and completely cover the screen` in the other answer. I agree that 20x20px would look ncie espacially on larger screens. 16x16 boxes in total look very large. Therefor I added a second snippet to the answer that adjust for that. I hope you like that - I do :)

Comment: I saw your code
```
    var containerWidth = Math.floor(container.offsetWidth / 20),
        containerHeight = Math.ceil(container.offsetHeight / 20);
    var squareAmmount = containerWidth * containerHeight;
```

Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```js
let x = 0;
let container = document.getElementById("container");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    createLongContainers();
    let longContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".longContainer");
    createBoxes(longContainers);
});

function createLongContainers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "longContainer";
        div.style.display = "flex";
        div.style.flexDirection = "row"
        div.style.justifyContent = "space-around"
        var lcHeight = "100%";
        div.style.height = lcHeight;
        div.style.width = "100%";
        container.appendChild(div);

    }
}

function createBoxes(longContainers) {
    longContainers.forEach((div) => {


        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            let box = document.createElement('div');
            box.className = "gridSquare";
            box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            box.onmouseover = function () {
                var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                box.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
                box.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
            };

            box.onmouseout = function () {
                box.style.transitionDuration = "3s";
                box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
            div.appendChild(box);

        }

    });
}
```

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%; 
}
.gridSquare {
    height: calc(100vh / 16);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Colorful Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script> 
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;"> <div id="container"></div><!-- Removes white border around page-->
</body>

</html>
```

Also try resizing it, it looks interesting because of the transition.

Comment: Not quite, no. I think some of it is a flaw in how I'm approaching this. Ideally I'm after divs that will be created dynamically depending on the size of the screen. These divs would have a fixed size, lets say 20px x 20px and completely cover the screen

Comment: Okay. Something like that would probably be made with `<canvas>`. They would need to change the amount of `div`s based on screen size.

Comment: `canvas` would be the wrong tool for it as it would not be interactive then. You would not get that animation anymore. But you are right that the ammount of `divs` must be changed depending on the viewport size. My second snippet shows how you would do that.

Comment: The reason I said canvas is because there is an issue with that script. When you resize the window, it won't work as expected. Another option instead of canvas is what you have currently, but instead detecting window resizes.